# Simple program in Swift. How is this fixed?

Tags: xcode, swift

How is this fixed? The idea is to return 0 when it is even, and return 1 when it isn't. I am not sure how to fix this. I have looked and there is nothing since this is such a new language.

**CODE:**

```
let numbers = 79
numbers({
    (number: Int) -> Int in
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return 1
    })
```

Comment: is that all of your code?

Comment: No, that is the snippet causing the error.

Comment: Could you describe the error?  What does the compiler/debugger say?

Comment: Why don't you just `return number % 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you set this up like you wanted to use the `map` function, but you never actually used map, or used an array as your variable. Try this.

```
let numbers = [79]

numbers.map({(number: Int) -> Int in
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return 1
})
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. How do I make it NOT use the map function though?

Comment: @user3677087 Well, if you're talking about fixing the code that you already have, this is the way to go. If however, you're willing to change how you try to solve the problem, I recommend you do what GoZoner suggested.

Comment: make sure you actually use the result of `numbers.map({})`, as it does not mutate `numbers` but returns the new array

Answer (score 2):

Define an `isEven()` function as such:

```
  9> func isEven (number:Int) -> Bool { return 0 == number % 2 }
 10> isEven(10)
$R6: Bool = true
 11> isEven(11)
$R7: Bool = false
```

If you are looking to `map` then:

```
numbers.map (isEven)
```

or, with a `lambda`:

```
numbers.map {(number:Int) -> Bool in return 0 == number % 2 }
```

as such:

```
 13> let numbers = [0, 1, 2]
 14> numbers.map { (n:Int) -> Bool in return 0 == n % 2 }
$R8: Bool[] = size=3 {
  [0] = true
  [1] = false
  [2] = true
}
```

In Swift, when a function is provided as the last argument in a function, like `map`, you don't need to enclose the lambda in parens.